# Ошибка обновления столбца MySQL

Tags: mysql, запрос

Понять не могу в чём проблема, есть запрос:

```
UPDATE `accounts` SET balance='3200' WHERE login='test'
```

Он работает, и есть такой запрос:

```
UPDATE `accounts` SET group='3' WHERE login='test'
```

Он не работает, Пишет такую ошибку:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group=3 WHERE login=test' at line 1

Как так? Так-же таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `login` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `balance` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `ip`, `group`, `balance`) VALUES
(1, 'test', 'test@mail.de', 'e430f779f7ff81de0e5b4c4f5e316672', '127.0.0.1', 2, 0);
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` - ключевое слово в `MYSQL`. Используется при группировке (`GROUP BY`).

Вот почему надо имена таблиц, колонок заключать в обратные кавычки! Или не называть колонки именами похожие на ключевые слова.

Ну и раз у тебя `group` имеет тип `int`, то может стоит вносить число, а не строку?

Comment: UPDATE `accounts` SET `group`=3 WHERE `login`='test' - Получилось!

Comment: @LightGryph0n естественно. будь осторожен при выборе имен

Answer (score 2):

> не работает, Пишет такую ошибку:

Когда сервер сообщает об ошибке, цитата фрагмента запроса начинается ровно с того символа, на котором возникла проблема. Поскольку сообщение выглядит как

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group=3 WHERE login=test' at line 1
```

то проблема именно в слове `group`. И это правильно - как уже отметил **Алексей Шиманский**, это зарезервированное слово, и его нужно квотировать (даже несмотря на то, что в некоторых случаях этот токен будет правильно распознан именно как имя поля):

```
UPDATE accounts SET `group`='3' WHERE login='test'
```

Ну и да - кавычки вокруг значения тут не к месту, тем более что тип поля - целое. Т.е.

```
UPDATE accounts SET `group`=3 WHERE login='test'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE `accounts` SET `group`=3 WHERE `login`='test'
```

Comment: "UPDATE accounts SET group=3 WHERE login='test'"
Так тоже не работает